# Another people's OpenPGP key in my computer?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, openpgp

Today, when I executed `gpg --list-keys`, I saw another people's key list here. I search in seahorse, but can not find it.

1. Is this key stored in my `pubring.gpg` file?
2. I only have one OpenPGP key for myself, so how can I find out where this key come from?

Comment: My version (gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.16) outputs a first line similar to `/home/user/.gnupg/pubring.gpg` for the `--list-keys` command, does yours not output a similar line? Try adding `-v` or more v's (more "verbose" I think 9's the max) like `-vvvvvvvvv` ?

Comment: gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.20.  my pubring.gpg filled with binary, not any ascii(plain-text) here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this key stored in my `pubring.gpg` file?

Yes, exactly. For GnuPG 2.1 and newer, it might also be the `pubring.kbx` file, which has a newer format that scales better for large number of keys.

> I only have one OpenPGP key for myself, so how can I find out where this key come from?

Mail clients often fetch keys "on the go" when you receive signed mails, so they can verify the signature. You could easily have fetched the key unnoticed, even from a mailing list post or similar incidents.

This is nothing to worry about. Having a key stored in your public keyring does not automatically make it trusted and valid.

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, consider marking it as accepted. Have a look at the [FAQ] on this.

Comment: I did it. but it says i need 15 reputation to do that. sadly.

Comment: I think this is only necessary for upvotes, not for "accepting" the answer. But don't worry, over time you'll get that reputation anyway if actively participating in questions and answers.